# Using arrow keys on Python shell prints garbage characters. How to fix?

Tags: linux, centos, python

Recently built Python 2.5.5 from source on a CentOS 5 box. Now whenever I type an arrow key in the standard Python shell, garbage characters gets printed. This doesn't happen with Python 2.4.

Also IPython shell loads with the following warning message:

```
WARNING: Readline services not available on this platform.
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `readline-devel` and rebuild.